# Validation rule to prevent field change

Tags: formula, validation-rule, account

I have trouble with this validation rule on Account. It should allow changes on MainBrand__c only if `MainBrand__pr.WebsiteRelevant__c` = true and `RegistrationDoubleOptin__c` = true. I tried this but not working:

```
AND(
            ISCHANGED(MainBrand__pc),

            MainBrand__pr.WebsiteRelevant__c,

            RegistrationDoubleOptIn__pc
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write a formula for the negative cases, not for the right one.
The validation rule should be triggered when `MainBrand__c` has been changed and either `MainBrand__pr.WebsiteRelevant__c` or `RegistrationDoubleOptin__c` are false (see [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), so the formula should be

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(MainBrand__pc),
    OR(
        NOT(MainBrand__pr.WebsiteRelevant__c),
        NOT(RegistrationDoubleOptin__c)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your validation rule is that you are using the wrong logical operator. You should use OR instead of AND, because you want to allow changes on `MainBrand__c` only if either of the two conditions are true, not both. Try this:

```
OR(
   NOT(ISCHANGED(MainBrand__pc)),
   AND(
       MainBrand__pr.WebsiteRelevant__c,
       RegistrationDoubleOptIn__pc
   )
)
```

This validation rule will only fire if `MainBrand__c` is changed and both `MainBrand__pr.WebsiteRelevant__c` and `RegistrationDoubleOptIn__pc` are false. Otherwise, it will allow the record to be saved.

Comment: Since you put `NOT(ISCHANGED(MainBrand__pc))` in OR with a different expression, the validation rule will be trigger everytime `MainBrand__pc` isn't changed, so everytime a user update any other field except `MainBrand__pc`